# How to access multidimensional array using django templates in html page

Tags: php, html, django, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in php page like this:

```
$comment=Array
(
    [655436] => 
    [655435] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5864928
            [shortmessage] => rytrht
        )

    [655434] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5864934
            [shortmessage] => vcxv
        )

    [654990] => 
    [654989] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5864948
            [shortmessage] => fgfj
        )

    [654983] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5864909
            [shortmessage] => state
        )

    [654981] => 
    [654979] => 
    [654978] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5864933
            [shortmessage] => ggjj
        )

    [654329] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5864974
            [shortmessage] => 
        )

)

echo $renderer->render('sample.html', array( 'index' => commentId,'Comment' => $comments));
```

I wish to use the $comment array values in HTML page using Django temlates with out looping over the array

sample.html:

```
<td><input class="Comment" type="text" value="{{Comment[index]['shormessage']}}" /></td>
```

But `{{Comment[index]['shormessage']}}` not giving any value and the whole page itself not displaying
I dont know how to access the multidimensional array.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: your question is little confusing, how exactly are you using django in your php project?

Comment: in my php page I have used render() and in html page django is used

Comment: @Nithya, just `php` it, don't complicate your life, http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php

Answer (score 0):

Use For Loop for this
Try by Using

```
{% for Comment in Comments %}

<input class="Comment" type="text" value="{{Comment.shormessage}}" />

{%endfor%}
```